# Java How to thread a GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

So I have a button that opens a while loop, then my whole GUI freezes until the while loop is over, with that being said how would I thread my GUI to update every second or so?

```
JButton Test= new JButton();
Test.setText("Test");
Test.setSize(230, 40);
Test.setVisible(true);
Test.setLocation(15, 290);

Test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
int x = 0;
while(x<500){
    x++
});
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ExecutorService` class

```
Test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            es.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int x = 0;
                    while (x < 500) {
                        x++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
 });
```

Comment: *"..how would I thread my GUI to update every second or so?"* The example code provided by the person asking the question was quite poor in that in the 'heavy lifting' loop it completely failed to even try to update the GUI! To do that 'update the GUI' it should be done on the EDT, whereas the heavy lifting itself should be off the EDT. As such the most optimal answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38813650/418556) which suggests using a `SwingWorker`.. The worker accounts for both and & off EDT code.

Answer (score 2):

the big idea is that your GUI freezes because you are doing heavy treatment in the thread responsible of drawing the GUI; the solution is to delegate calculations or any treatments that are susceptible of taking time to a thread that will be executed in the background.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious because Swing objects are not thread safe and so you're provided with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, which allows a task to be executed at some later point in time.

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      int x = 0;
      while(x<500){
          x++
      }
    }
});
```